# QT creator Build fails unless administrator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a QT project in QT creator. I have been getting strange behavior from it. Unless I open QT Creator with administrative permissions, it won't build at all complaining that it can't start process qmake (qmake is in the right place). My shadow build specifies ..\bin folder as the build. My complete structure is:

```
project
|
+--- bin
+--- src
```

So they are at the same level. What could be the issue here?
The problem is that when I use administrator rights, the project builds in C:\Users\bin which isn't right right place.

The actual error given is:

Could not start process "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\qmake.exe"

Comment: Which permissions are set on qmake? Can your user execute it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a number of your paths or locations may be off.  They could be in the Qt Projects Configure dialog or it could be in your .pro file.

Does a simple "Hello World" example build, without editing the defaults for the folder structures?  Do the examples of the Qt SDK build?

Did you install Qt at the root of the C drive?  Nesting it in your documents or somewhere else can put a space in the Qt Path variable, which I don't think is supported well by Qt Creator and QMake without a lot of work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. Examples do build when I don't use administrator mode. I installed QT in the default path

Comment: What are the permissions of your project folders?  It sounds like you might be building where the user isn't allowed to edit files.  Right click on the folder/folders you are using and go to the security tab and see who is allowed to read and write to the folder.

Comment: I tried.Interestingly enough trying to change the permissions to give everyone full control pops up a display saying that I cannot change permissions despite being an admin. I'll look more into this